# How to start multiple ssh-session from a bash script

Tags: bash, process

Beeing in home office, i need to start every morning  some ssh-tunnels to  my company to get my inhouse workplace applications websites via portforwarding to my desktop.
Every ssh call is inside his own script and every ssh-tunnel need a keyphrase to unlock the ssh-key needed for that connection.

I#m bored of manually starting every morning those scripts (which starts the ssh-tunnels) and would like to start them all at one and typing in only one time the keyphrase.

like

```
!/bin/sh
./start-tunnel-app1.sh &
./start-tunnel-app2.sh &
...
./start-tunnel-appX.sh
```

and start-tunnel-app1.sh like

```
!/bin/sh
~/.ssh/mykeyfile -L 8000:companyserver1:8000 mylogin@companygateway.com
```

with the keyfile protected by a passphrase.

how to do such a thing correctly? That i only need to start one script and type in one time the password to start multiple ssh sessions like this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is mentioned in [this Q/A](https://superuser.com/questions/1313738/how-to-run-a-tunnel-in-the-background-as-part-of-a-shell-script) will be better to use `-f` instead of `&`.

And also before start the script start `ssh-agent` to create passwordless start of `ssh`

Comment: Thanks, that's working.
But now another question.

How to list & kill the ss-client sessions on my home computer. Not on the server side, but on "my" side. 
As the ssh-sessions are created in the background, i did not have a terminal session to "exit" from.

Comment: @Chris9834, please create new question

Comment: OK it is working fine, but now i see that i tricked myself.

Opening all the ssh-sessions in the background and automaticlly is fine, as long as did not need a remote shell.
But sometimes i need this. So my additional question is how to start all that ssh-tunnels not in background, but in multiple own bash-sessions/Windows?

So that i start the script which starts all my ssh sessions and i end up with a multiple terminals on my desktop each one showing me the remote machine i connected to via ssh.

Answer (score 0):

You can etablish the first ssh connexion with authentication, and use this open connexion for the other ssh sessions (without authentication needed). See man ssh and the option ControlMaster .